# VSCode не может найти vector. Программирование Arduino

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, arduino

[image: Структура проекта]

Структура файлов приведена на скриншоте.
В файле ConnectorDB.cpp выполняется `#include <vector>`
При сборке получаю ошибку: `sketch\src\ConnectorDB.cpp:5:10: fatal error: vector: No such file or directory`
Понимаю, что программа не может найти файл "vector"

В ./vscode/c_cpp_properties.json прописано:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools\\**",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**",
                "D:\\vahtaClient\\src",
                "D:\\vahtaClient\\headers",
                "D:\\vahtaClient\\lib\\**",
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\include\\**"
            ],
            "forcedInclude": [
                "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\cores\\arduino\\Arduino.h"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path":[
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\tools\\**",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Arduino\\hardware\\arduino\\avr\\**",
                    "D:\\vahtaClient\\src",
                    "D:\\vahtaClient\\headers",
                    "D:\\vahtaClient\\lib\\**",
                    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.24.28314\\include"
                ]   
            },
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.24.28314/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Фрагмент файла ConnectorDB.cpp

```
#ifndef CONNECTORDB_H
#define CONNECTORDB_H

#include "../headers/ConnectorDB.h"
#include <vector>

ConnectorDB::ConnectorDB() {}
```

Comment: а Вы уверенны, что компилятор под ардуино умеет vector? я к примеру - нет.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, приведенная конфигурация - это конфигурация модели кода vs code, которая нужна, чтобы нормально работала подсветка синтаксиса и автоподстановка, на сборку это не влияет. Причем путь к msvs там, вероятно, лишний. Собираете то вы как?

Answer (score 1):

По ссылке описаны ограничения C++ в Arduino:

> ## 2. [C++ limitations](https://roboticsbackend.com/the-arduino-language-in-10-points/#2_C++_limitations)
>
> So, if the Arduino language is a subset of C++, then does that mean
> that you can use all the C++ functionalities?
>
> Unfortunately, the answer is no – at least with the Arduino core.
>
> Here are some of the main C++ features you can’t use with Arduino:
>
> - STL library. Forget about using std::vector for lists, std::string, or std::map (well, in fact you can use an external library to still
>   get some functionalities from vectors, strings, etc). You’ll have to
>   define your arrays yourself and manage their space. Anyway, the
>   Arduino memory is far more smaller than your computer memory, so
>   managing memory is a real matter here. You’ll want to make your arrays
>   as small as possible. For strings though, you can use the built-in
>   Arduino String type.
> - Exceptions. You’ll have to deal with error codes in returned values!

Если кратко - то недоступен STL (но если очень хочется, то можно установить библиотеку с реализацией, но она ест очень много памяти), а также механизм исключений.

Если все же очень хочется пользоваться функционалом STL, то по этой ссылке [инструкция по установке библиотеки](https://roboticsbackend.com/arduino-stl-library/).